# Let $a_1,a_2,a_3,...,a_n$ be elements of a group $(G,*)$. Show by induction that $a_1*a_2*a_3...*a_n$ always gives the same answer.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Basically I need to prove that a group $(G,*)$ is associative in the general case. To do this I know I have to use induction to show that no matter where I insert parentheses into the equation $a_1*a_2*a_3...*a_n$ I will always get the same result.

The first step is to show that $(G,*)$ is associative in the smallest possible case, where $n=3$. Clearly if $n=3$ we get $$a*(b*c)=(a*b)*c$$ as $(G,*)$ is a group and we have exhausted all the possibilities as to where we can put the parentheses.

Next we assume $(G,*)$ is associative for $n$ elements and show that it is still associative for $n+1$ elements. We have $$a_1*(a_2*(a_3*(...*(a_{n-1}*(a_n*a_{n+1})...))))$$ This is where I'm stuck, how do I show that if it works for $n$ elements it must work for $n+1$?

Comment: Hint: Use *strong* induction. Show that if the result is true for all $k\lt n$, it is true for $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The outermost bracketing is $$(a_1a_2 \cdots a_k)(a_{k+1}a_{k+2}\cdots a_{n+1})$$ for some $k$ with $1 \le k \le n$. By induction, the inner bracketing of the two bracketed terms makes no difference to the result.

The result will follow if we can show that the product for any value of $k$ is the same as it is for $k=1$. So suppose that $k>1$. Then the product is equal to

$$(a_1(a_2 \cdots a_k))(a_{k+1}a_{k+1}\cdots a_{n+1}),$$

which, by the associativity group axiom is equal to

$$a_1((a_2 \cdots a_k)(a_{k+1}a_{k+1}\cdots a_{n+1})),$$

which is the case $k=1$, and we are done.

Comment: I'm confused as to why $a_{k+1}$ appears twice in the second term. Also, I'm not sure if I'm not understanding or just nitpicking but is there an extra parenthesis in the last equation?

Comment: why you divided whole expression at k ?

Comment: @Olivia I don't really understand your question. I am defining $k$ to be the number at which the expression is bracketed.

Comment: @DerekHolt i don't get idea of proof

Comment: @Olivia I cannot help unless you tell me exactly what it is that you don't get. There were a few typos in my post, which I have now corrected.

Comment: @DerekHolt "The result will follow if we can show that the product for any value of k
 is the same as it is for k=1 "

Comment: @Olivia The proof is by induction on $n$, with base case $n=3$, which is true by assumption. If we have two bracketings $B_1$ and $B_2$ with $k=1$, then  it follows by applying the inductive hypotheses for the case $n-1$ to the two  bracketings of the product $a_2a_3 \cdots a_{n+1}$ in $B_1$ and $B_2$ that the $B_1$ and $B_2$ evaluate to the same element. So if any bracketing  gives the same result as one with $k=1$, then any two bracketings must give the same result.